# Delay before booting?

Tags: boot, delay

Booting will start only after 5-10 minutes.

If we go for BIOS, it will also take that much time.

At that time monitor showing intel pentium 4 logo.

My Mother board is intel 845 GlAD and  Processor is INTEL P4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have USB devices connected to the computer? Try disconnecting them.

I had the same kind of issues when my Palm TX was connected when the computer was rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

I had that same problem when the power supply was going out.  The computer would take longer and longer to start from when I pressed the power button.  After replacing the power supply the computer would start immediately after pressing the power button.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Snark reminded me of an answer to a similar question, which *I thought* I had 'favorited' but didn't.

I recall that one of the answers suggested the problem was Legacy USB support in the BIOS, and that it could be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, legacy USB is usually compulsory if you want to be able to use your USB mouse and keyboards from the login screen, at least the first time you boot Windows, and before you could install Windows drivers for them (they'll be automatic from Windows XP and newer, of course, but they still have to be loaded at least once. BTW, turn "Plug and play OS" option on in your BIOS settings).

And anyway, I've never experienced such problem. Actually, it should always be better to activate legacy USB if you wan't risk to get stuck with no keyboard nor mouse. The fun fact is the BIOS perfectly recognizes any kind of peripheral, but not the OS if you don't turn this feature on...

Well, anyway, I really don't think the problem is there.

I'd rather investigate other boot options, such as LAN boot ROM (it was originally a real add-on ROM and had to be inserted in its socket), boot from LAN, boot from diskette (that's unlikely to be present nowadays), etc. : if the system is checking all absent peripherals in turn, it may well result in a strong lag...

First, go to your boot options tab, browse through the hard drives list and ensure your main hard drive is first in the list, then in the main boot order list and check you've put your hard drive in first position as well (though you might also want to put your CD-ROM drive first in case you need to boot from there ; in this case, put your hard drive in second position), and disable all the rest rather than leaving them in the list.

Then check you Sata options in advanced setup.

If you're running your P4 with Windows XP, for instance, you should turn your Sata controller into "IDE" or "standard" or "legacy" more, NOT into "AHCI" or "Ehanced" or "sata" mode, as XP shouldn't even boot from them. Maybe yours can but is struggling. If you notice it's in the wrong mode, however, you may have to reinstall Windows after switching to the correct one...

Note that there's a registry key that can allow you to boot windows 7 under both AHCI and IDE mode. I'm using it with my spare Windows XP boot so I can put back the BIOS into IDE mode and boot both (WP is just in case of emergency, so I can still work and access my data incase the main OS crashes).

Then on more recent motherboards, you have to turn UEFI mode off if you're using any OS older than Windows 8 or you'll experience big trouble as well.

Now of course, it might also simply come from your hard disk dying and losing clusters. Once you've booted, have you checked it using Speedfan (or any other S.M.A.R.T. report reader) ?

And finally, add-on controller cards may have their own ROM and take some additional boot time. SCSI and RAID cards are known for this, but they always display some information onscreen and a delay allowing you to hit some keys to access their own settings, so you should obviously know.

In this case, a broken raid array is very likely to cause such delay at boot (but once again, it should clearly be displayed, so you could hardly ignore it).