# Delay before booting with laptop

Tags: laptop, boot

I have almost the same problem as in [Delay before booting?](https://superuser.com/questions/101099/delay-before-booting)
My computer is a practically new (couple months) Lenovo X200 Tablet (System Model 7449FXG).
So when I press the power button, the indicator light that means "computer is on" turns on, but nothing else happens for about 5 mins, after that the computer starts booting normally. The same happens also on restart. And no USB or any other device for that matter is plugged in to the computer. And at the delay time the monitor is blank - actually not on at all.

**[update]**

I ended up giving my computer to local IBM / Lenovo Service and they replaced the mainboard. They did not check (or did not want to tell me :) ) what was the exact cause of the problem though. But I am happy that my computer boots up normally again :)
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have enable a POST other than the usual quick POST?  Some BIOSs will allow a more detailed POST and that takes some time.  The default is usually the Quick version

Comment: No, my POST is set to `Quick`. (instead of the other option - `Diagnostics`)  
I am starting to think that it could be a hardware issue. No changes in settings were made and I suspect the laptop could have gotten too hot at some point. It was running quite for a long time one day and after that this behavior started...

Comment: Can you run the Lenovo PCdoctor app and see if it finds anything?

Comment: I ran the Lenovo PCDoctor. It could not run some graphics tests and the suggestion was to get updated drivers. I have not done that yet - will try.
I guess the big problem might be somehow related to graphics problems because the monitor is not switching on at the beginning, but since the tests chocked (actually only some specific DirectX related tests) because of a driver problem, I don't think this relates much to my problem of delay at start...

Comment: Lenovo also has a tool that will check the system and downlaod the latest drivers for you. ThinkVanatage System Update. It will find any updated drivers and allow you to download and install.  It will also do BIOS updates

Comment: I used the Lenovo tool to update drivers and run the diagnostics tool again. This time it passed all the tests. The delay now is getting even longer - up to 9 minutes. I will probably give the computer to Lenovo's "tech support" for hardware check...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flashing the BIOS? It is whats holding you up, so just flash it and see if it does anything.

Also see what happens if you move your disk to the first boot priority.

Comment: There have been 2 BIOS updates (newer versions) performed since the problem started and it did not change anything. The boot order also was changed but it does not help. The hangup happens before the first ThinkPad logo appears, so before the boot sequence even starts...
I am bringing the computer to local Lenovo service for hardware check next week (had to work until now and had no time to do it sooner)... I'll happily report back what they find...